# Terminology for matrix whose rows are permutations of a given multiset.

Tags: matrices, terminology, multisets

Let $X=\{a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{m}\}$ be a multiset. Is there a name for an $n\times m$ matrix $A$ such that the entries of each row of $A$ are equal to the set $X$.

For example, if $X=\{1,1,2,3,3\}$ and $n=5$, then we could take

$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 \\
1 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$